# Python read csv file and add one column through function computation

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have an example csv file with name 'r2.csv':

```
Factory | Product_Number |   Date     |   mu   |   cs   |  co 
--------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 01APR2017  |   5.6  |  125   |  275
--------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 02APR2017  |   4.5  |  200   |  300
--------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 03APR2017  |   6.6  |  150   |  250
--------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 04APR2017  |   7.5  |  175   |  325
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to add one more column with name `'Order_Number'`. With the following function

`Order_Number = np.ceil(poisson.ppf(co/(cs+co), mu))`

With the following code I have:

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.stats import poisson, norm
    import csv

    # Read Data
    with open('r2.csv', 'r') as infile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
        data = {}
        for row in reader:
            for header, value in row.items():
                try:
                    data[header].append(value)
                except KeyError:
                    data[header] = [value]

    # To create a list for the following parameters 
    mu = data['mu']
    cs = data['cs']
    co = data['co']

    # Obtain Order_Number 
    Order_Number = np.ceil(poisson.ppf(co/(cs+co), mu))
```

Before Obtaining 'Order_Number' it works fine. And 'Order_Number' function it has the following error: 
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'**

How could I change my code in order to obtain the following table as output：

```
Factory | Product_Number |   Date    |  mu  | cs  | co  | Order_Number
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 01APR2017 |  5.6 | 125 | 275 |   ?
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 02APR2017 |  4.5 | 200 | 300 |   ?
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 03APR2017 |  6.6 | 150 | 250 |   ?
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   A    |      1         | 04APR2017 |  7.5 | 175 | 325 |   ?
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I am not sure if you have the ability to install packages in your current environment, but if you can, you should really consider installing `pandas`.  It would make this type of data manipulation rather trivial.  In general, you might like the suite of packages offered at [pydata](https://pydata.org/downloads.html)

Comment: Thanks! @tipanverella I am currently using Anaconda Navigator, and could install 'pandas'. However, as suggestion actual production level may not have 'pandas' package and I have to consider if normal way will work or not currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your content of `mu`, `cs` and `co` is  list of strings.
First convert that to `float`.

```
mu = map(float,mu)  
cs = map(float,cs)  
co = map(float,co)
```

Then , since you have list of values you need to map your `np.ceil(poisson.ppf(co/(cs+co), mu))` function to each value of these lists.

`Order_Number =map(lambda mu_,cs_,co_:np.ceil(poisson.ppf(co_/(cs_+co_),mu_)),mu,cs,co)`

Result is as follows,

```
>>> map(lambda mu_,cs_,co_:np.ceil(poisson.ppf(co_/(cs_+co_), mu_)),mu,cs,co)
[7.0, 5.0, 7.0, 8.0]
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT-1**

Code to add data to an `csv` file. You may want to look at opening your `csv` to `orderedDict` so that you dont need to write each column headers manually. Yo can just call `data.keys()`.

```
#Covnert string element of list to float
mu = map(float,mu)  
cs = map(float,cs)  
co = map(float,co)

# Obtain Order_Number 
Order_Number =map(lambda mu_,cs_,co_:np.ceil(poisson.ppf(co_/(cs_+co_),mu_)),mu,cs,co)

#Add Oder_Number to the data dict
data['Order_Number'] = Order_Number
header = 'Factory','Product_Number','Date','mu','cs','co','Order_Number'
#Add data to csv
with open("output.csv",'wb') as resultFile:
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(header)
    z = zip(data['Factory'],data['Product_Number'],data['Date'],data['mu'],data['cs'],data['co'],data['Order_Number'])
    for i in z:
        wr.writerow(i)
```

**Result**  [image]

Comment: Thank you! @Anil_M.  That works well for me and I can return `[7.0, 5.0, 7.0, 8.0]`  And how could I add this column to prior data?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, additional question: If I would like to define a function that can work for an array as you suggested above.                                                       `G = poisson(mu)
 p = G.pmf(np.arange(3*mu))                                                                         def Z(Q):
    for i in range(len(p)):
        yield p[i]*cs1*max((Q-i), 0) + p[i]*co1*max((i-Q), 0)`                    How could I make it happen? As it has same error message **ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar. ** Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a different question and let me know. As per SO etiquette Different questions needs to be asked in different question.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @Anil_M  posted with name 'Python change the function to compute for an array'.

Answer (score 0):

As created

```
mu = data['mu']
cs = data['cs']
co = data['co']
```

are lists of strings.  Look at them, or at least a subset, e.g `mu[:10]`.  You can't do array math with lists

```
co/(cs+co)
```

`cs+co` will concatenate the 2 lists (`+` definition for lists), but `/` is not defined for lists.

```
mu = np.array(data, dtype=float)
cs = ....
co
```

might do the trick, converting the lists into 1d numpy arrays.

An alternative is to use `np.genfromtxt` with `dtype=None` and `names=True` to load the data into a structured array.  But then I'd have to explain how to access the named fields.  And unfortunately adding a new field to this array (the calc results) isn't trivial.  And writing a new csv from a structured array requires some extra knowledge.

Try the list to array conversion.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj,  thanks and that's the issue, and I used it to convert and got solution. And from your description add a new field to my 'data' how shall I complete this procedure?

Comment: If you are already used to reading with the `csv` Reader, it's probably simplest to stick with that for writing.

Comment: Yep, forgive my naive